# Can't find .NET MAUI in the list of VS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, maui, maui-blazor

I want to create a new project by using .NET MAUI,  In Microsoft tutorial they said the Prerequisites is `The latest preview of Visual Studio 2022 17.1`, after installing the last preview version with `.NET MAUI`, I couldn't find the project from the list. 
**This what I did**[image]

[image]

Can some give me ad advise to go around this problem.
**Thanks**

Comment: Restart Visual Studio and search at the top for MAUI, if it's still not getting found, restart your PC. If that doesn't help, you can try reinstalling/unchecking mobile development and rechecking/reinstalling it, which might fix the issue, it has worked first try for me. It is preview/beta software which means that there are bugs, so everything might not work as expected. Kind Regards!

Comment: Also try running “Repair” on that VS, in VS Installer.

Comment: Still not solved with visual studio comm 2022--17.7.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why this sometimes happens, what fixes it is to install the templates manually at this time. From an (elevated) command prompt run: `dotnet new --install Microsoft.Maui.Templates`

That should succeed and the templates should then be visible in Visual Studio as well.

Comment: Does the command maui-check solve this issue as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what the current status is of maui-check. I _think_ it should, but not 100% sure. I think for workloads and templates the official tooling is now recommended

Answer (score 0):

Update VS Code. I think that will solve your problem.

That's work. I update it on version 17.9.0.
[image]